# How to filter some consecutive elements from an array in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

If I have an array of names like

```
names = ["Muneeb", "Roshan", "Umar", "Kamil", "Shamseer", "Ajay", "Jasar"]
```

and I want to filter this array in a way that select two elements from this array which has an index of 3 and 4. How to achieve this by AngularJS ng-repeat? Please advise.

Comment: `new_names = [names[3], names[4]]`

Comment: Try `ng-repeat="name in [names[3], names[4]]"`?

Comment: Seems highly unlikely that you would only be using hard code index values. Please elaborate on full problem and show what you have attempted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can use an ng-if on the index, something like

```
<div ng-repeat = "name in names track by $index">
  <div ng-if="$index === 3 || $index === 4">Whatever you want here</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-bind` directive

Here is an example:

**HTML**

```
<main ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainController">

  <article ng-bind="arr[3]"></article>
  <article ng-bind="arr[4]"></article>

</main>
```

**JS**

```
angular.module('myApp', [])

  .controller('MainController', function($scope) {
    $scope.arr = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five'];
  });
```